# Let us suppose vs Suppose

Tags: science, academia, academic-writing, scientific-language

When should we use "Let us suppose", and when "Suppose" in  science  academic articles?

**Example 1:**

> Suppose the electric field lines in a region of space are straight lines.

or

> Let us suppose the electric field lines in a region of space are straight lines.

**Example 2:**

> Let us suppose the particle is in a stationary state with definite energy E.

or

> Suppose the particle is in a stationary state with definite energy E.

Comment: It's more usual to use assume not suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is little or no difference.  Personally, I tend to use both of these indiscriminately.

---

The following perhaps has no basis in practice?

If the rest of the article is in first person plural ("us", "we"), continue that here and write "Let us suppose..."

If the rest of the article in the second person ("you" or just imperative), continue that here and write "Suppose..."